# Read a file continously via HTTP with Java

Tags: java, http, inputstream

What I need to do is basically reading a file which is continously growing, but in every interval I just want to read the **new** that was appended to the file.

I found a lot of ways to do this with a file on my filesystem, but all these require that I download the file before I can do the *magic* using the `RandomAccessFile`-Object.

Is there a way to do this with an online-file like http://myurl.com/123.txt? So that I just stream the data added in the last 2 minutes?

Thanks a lot!
noise

Comment: This file, is it hosted in a server you own?

Comment: no. i have no influence on the server or the file. I just know the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the server supports it, you can use the [`Range`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35) header to request bytes from a given offset. Do this repeatedly to poll the file for new bytes.

Pseudocode:

```
long offset = 0;
while (true) {
    request.setHeader("Range: bytes=" + offset + "-");
    request.send();
    request.readResponse();
    offset += theNumberOfBytesRead;
    Thread.sleep(someRespectfulAmountOfTime);
}
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303029/http-range-header) for details about how the server is likely to respond if it does or doesn't have more bytes available.

To get "data added in the last 2 minutes", you have to keep track of what `offset` was two minutes ago.