# How to force full HTTP delivery when client requests Range?

Tags: http, http-headers

Let's say a client makes a request like the following (pulled from iOS):

```
GET /test.mp4 HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com:80
Range: bytes=0-1
X-Playback-Session-Id: 3DFA3BE3-CB22-4EC5-808F-B59A735DCECE
Accept-Encoding: identity
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-us
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: AppleCoreMedia/1.0.0.11B554a (iPad; U; CPU OS 7_0_4 like Mac OS X; en_us)
```

There other such requests out there, I believe Chrome might test the waters by asking for blank Range.

How can the server respond to any such request so that it does not need to honor Range , but rather treat it as a standard HTTP delivery, and the client will play the file?

Sending a regular header response and the data as though the client were not asking for Range does not seem to work.

**EDIT:** Conversely, if the client does *not* request a Range, is it okay to respond with HTTP 206 with full filesize in Content-Length and also Content-Range header (which client will ignore)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Http Range header](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303029/http-range-header)

Answer (score 1):

If the server does not support the `Range` header, it would send a normal `200` reply to send the entire file.  If the server supports the `Range` header, it would send a `206` or `416` reply, depending on whether the requested range can be satisfied or not.  This is covered in [RFC 2616 Section 14.35](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.35).

It is not OK to respond with `206`  if the client did not request a `Range`.

Comment: What's strange is that when I try this to serve an mp4 to iOS, it fails. Is it acceptable that a client will *require* a server to satisfy Range requests?

Answer (score 0):

Try responding with HTTP 1.0 - it doesn't support range requests at all.

Maybe the client will treat such a reply more gracefully.