# How to read a large file(>1GB) in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I use ajax $.get to read a file at local server. However, the web crashed since my file was too large(> 1GB). How can I solve the problem? If there's other solutions or alternatives?

```
$.get("./data/TRACKING_LOG/GENERAL_REPORT/" + file, function(data){
        console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: do you have access to the server generating the report?

Comment: humm, not feasible, better to load data in pages with LIMIT

Comment: You could try to split it in multiple pages and sending one based on a get parameter such as website.com/?pagelen=10000&pagenum=1

Comment: Did the whole web crash or the web server or the web browser?

Comment: Dude *YOU* did **crash** our **web**?!

Comment: what is the type of your local server, what do you run on it?

Comment: A gig?  In a browser?  With ajax?

Comment: @Musa only my web browser crashed, and could anyone explain how to split file into pages? cuz I just read in a large csv file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading files in chunks using AJAX + Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44493340/reading-files-in-chunks-using-ajax-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

A solution, assuming that you don't have control over the report generator, would be to download the file in multiple smaller pieces, using [range headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303029/http-range-header), process the piece, extract what's needed from it (I assume you'll be building some html components based on the report), and move to the next piece.

You can tweak the piece size until you find a reasonable value for it, a value that doesn't make the browser crash, but also doesn't result in a large number of http requests.

If you can control the report generator, you can configure it to generate multiple smaller reports instead of a huge one.

Answer (score 0):

Split the file into a lot of files or give a set user ftp access.  I doubt you'd want too many people downloading a gig each off your web server.