# converting an fetch api call to ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i am using a code from a site where onsubmit the call is made and a call is made

```
$(":submit").click(async (event) => {
```

i am not aware of this syntax.

my example using the simple `$.ajax` call and making a post call to the page

so the above function is like this

```
$(":submit").click(async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        let response = await fetch("page.cfm");
        const reader = response.body.getReader();
        const len = response.headers.get("Content-Length") * 1;
```

my ajax call is like this

```
$.ajax({
                url: "page.cfm",
                cache: false,
                data : $('#form').serialize(),
                method: "post",
                beforeSend: function() {
                    $('div.results').html('Please wait');
                },
                success: function(response){
                    $('div.results').html(response);
                }
```

how can i format the above to my ajax call

Comment: above fetch is using `GET` but in your ajax you are using `POST`

Comment: i tried with post too

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions, async generators and modules

Comment: this is my full function code https://jsfiddle.net/Lpcva7n4/

Comment: You can put every line after `await fetch` inside the success function of your ajax call.
Learn how async/await is working. Here is a quick tutorial:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await

Comment: What is the result that gives you ajax call ??

Comment: remove the ajax keyword

Comment: can anyone right some correct code, here its just bits of pieces of information and nothing working

Comment: I didn't understand your question. Do you: 1) need to change your `ajax` code to be implemented using `fetch`? or 2) need to change your `fetch` code to be implemented using `ajax`? If it's 2), make sure you read [this answer first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44497008/3247017) as it explains why you should use `fetch` instead of `XMLHTTPRequest` based methods (like `$.ajax`) to read responses in small chunks.

Answer (score 0):

Include form data in the body.  Make sure that your await fetch is inside async functions.

```js
$('document').ready( async function() {
  $("#test_fetch").submit( async function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
    var form = $(this);
    var url = form.attr('action');
            
    let response = await fetch(url,{
      method:"post",
      body: $(form).serialize()
    });
    ...
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the request to POST and pass the data.
Then read the data from the response

```
$(":submit").click(async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('div.results').html('Please wait');
    let response = await fetch("page.cfm", {method: 'POST', headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}, body: $('#form').serialize()});
    const html = await response.text();
    $('div.results').html(html);
});
```