# Python DevAppServer HTTP "Range: 0-" returns 500 error

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

I'm using google cloud storage to store and serve mp3 files, I want to access it on the devapp server but it doesn't accept the HTTP header Range formatted like this: `Range:bytes=0-`, but it accepts `Range:bytes=0-64`

I want to use this file from an audio tag like this `<audio src="http://localhost:8080/_ah/gcs/sound/97f2baf2-530e-426c-a281-0bca5135f1c1.mp3"></audio>` but Chrome and Firefox will always issue a `Range:bytes=0-` header, leading to the failure of the request.

My question is, is this due to using the devapp server? (or will it work magically on production?)

Comment: According to this discussion, the Range header '''should''' work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303029/http-range-header

Comment: I saw and worked on your bug report here [1]. Anyone having similar issues should star the thread and add their voice.

Comment: Hi @Ryan, is there an issue in google tracker for this one? I would like to track the progress

Comment: Any updates for the issue will be added here: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11750 including questions and confirmation when the work is finished.