# NodeJS express throwing RangeNotSatisfiableError, How to reproduce it?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Every day randomly I get these errors, This makes node non-responsive. I am not able to reproduce it. How can I do it?

`Jul 21 12:38:38 localhost Pchat.log RangeNotSatisfiableError: Range Not Satisfiable
Jul 21 12:38:38 localhost Pchat.log    at SendStream.error (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/send/index.js:275:31)
Jul 21 12:38:38 localhost Pchat.log    at SendStream.send (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/send/index.js:618:19)
Jul 21 12:38:38 localhost Pchat.log    at onstat (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/send/index.js:677:10)
Jul 21 12:38:38 localhost Pchat.log    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:83:15)
Jul 21 12:38:38 localhost Pchat.log RangeNotSatisfiableError: Range Not Satisfiable
Jul 21 12:38:38 localhost Pchat.log    at SendStream.error (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/send/index.js:275:31)
Jul 21 12:38:38 localhost Pchat.log    at SendStream.send (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/send/index.js:618:19)
Jul 21 12:38:38 localhost Pchat.log    at onstat (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/send/index.js:677:10)
Jul 21 12:38:38 localhost Pchat.log    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:83:15)
Jul 21 12:38:38 localhost Pchat.log RangeNotSatisfiableError: Range Not Satisfiable
Jul 21 12:38:38 localhost Pchat.log    at SendStream.error (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/send/index.js:275:31)
Jul 21 12:38:38 localhost Pchat.log    at SendStream.send (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/send/index.js:618:19)
Jul 21 12:38:38 localhost Pchat.log    at onstat (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/send/index.js:677:10)
Jul 21 12:38:38 localhost Pchat.log    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:83:15)`

Comment: have you found a way to fix this issue?

Comment: Added a middleware to my express app which does not throw it into the app, Also increased the memory stack of node.

Comment: Which middleware have u added? How can I add. So it does not throw the exception in the node app ? And you increased the stack of node by node --stack_size=8192 --max-old-space-size=8192 ?

Comment: Yes, I am using standard express error handling middleware. You can see it here. https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html

Comment: Thanks, if I use express error handling, then will it not crash my node app ?
right now i am using node error handling. process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
  console.log("Uncaught Exception:", err);
  process.exit(1);  // This is VITAL. Don't swallow the err and try to continue.
});

Comment: Keep this if you like, Express won't bypass this error to node.

Comment: okay, do you think using this simple error handle of express would be enough to get where and why errors are coming without crashing my node server? app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  console.error(err.stack);
  res.status(500).send('Something broke!');
});

Comment: If and only iff error is coming via express, I express is not involved and you are still getting an error, Then ur process might crash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like [send package](https://github.com/pillarjs/send/) error. It occurs when request contains header `Content-Range` with [unreachable range of stream](https://groggystuff.wordpress.com/2014/10/02/resolving-http-error-416-requested-range-not-satisfiable-iis-7-5-example/) (paragraph #3). It's better to add an issue into send package.

To reproduce it try to send `Content-Range`. But before look [how it works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18745164/884491).

Comment: @hardeep have you solved this problem, if so plz share your solution

Comment: Same issue occurred for me. when I transfer file or data of length 0B. To reproduce issue try to send data of length 0 Bytes

Comment: @SANTHOSH.SJ If you need help with this, create new question with detailed information about your issue.