# stream video file mp4 with Spring Boot 2 Controller StreamingResponseBody

Tags: java, spring-boot, controller, video-streaming, streamingresponsebody

I'm trying to stream a video file mp4 with Spring Boot 2 , I followed some tutorial and the solution should be simple... like the controller I copied below...  but don't work for me.

I cant understand why..
When I put the url in my browser, the default video player appear, loading...
after a timeout i receive a "net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH 200 " in the browser console..

If I omit the headers.add("Content-Length", Long.toString(file.length()));  the loading is very fast but nothing happen...

```
@Controller
public class StreamController {

    @RequestMapping(path = { "/stream-video-file" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> streamFile(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) {

        File file = new File("/path/to/file.mp4");
        if (!file.isFile()) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body(null);

        }

        StreamingResponseBody stream = out -> {

            try {
                final InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

                byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
                int length;
                while ((length = inputStream.read(bytes)) >= 0) {
                    out.write(bytes, 0, length);
                }
                inputStream.close();
                out.flush();

            } catch (final Exception e) {
                LOG.error("Exception while reading and streaming data {} ", e);
            }

        };

        final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Content-Type", "video/mp4");
        headers.add("Content-Length", Long.toString(file.length()));

        return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).body(stream);
    }
}
```

What I'm missing?...

EDIT ----

I find another way to do the job, without using StreamingResponseBody, but using the response header "Range-Content" .

A very good explanation here: [HTTP Range header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303029/http-range-header#answer-18745164)

and here:  https://github.com/saravanastar/video-streaming

Answer (score 1):

Comment this line:

```java
headers.add("Content-Type", "video/mp4");
```